# Plotting a 2D iso-probability curve

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, data-visualization

I have a library function that returns a pair of two numbers like this

```
def library_function(x0, x1):
    return x0**2 + x1**2, 10*x0*x1 + 1
```

(Actually, it is [a function that returns predicted probabilities of two classes for some object](http://pybrain.org/docs/api/structure/networks.html#pybrain.structure.networks.Network.activate), but it doesn't matter, so I created an artificial one.) I want to draw contours where the difference between two numbers returned by `library_function` is zero. To do so, I have to create a two-dimensional list (or array) with the differences.

I have the following possibilities:

```
X0 = np.linspace(-10, 10, 200)
X1 = np.linspace(-10, 10, 200)

results = [[(lambda u: u[0]-u[1])(library_function(x0, x1)) 
            for x0 in X0] for x1 in X1]
plt.contour(X0, X1, results, [0])
```

This approach is concise but I have to introduce `lambda` which seem to be considered not so Pythonic.

Another way:

```
values = [[library_function(x0, x1) for x0 in X0] for x1 in X1]
results = [[a-b for a, b in row] for row in values]
```

I have to introduce temporary two-dimensional list and this approach is longer.

Are there any ideas how to do it better (more concise and readable)?

Comment: Why must you have a single `library_function` that returns a pair? Perhaps it would be better as two functions? I think I would like to see what your real `library_function` is.

Comment: It's pybrain's [.activate()](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/network.html) method. It returns a predicted vector. I use it as two-class classifier and my output space is two-dimensional, and I'd like to draw a border between two classes, so I have to calculate the difference between the plausibilities returned by the function `activate()` and compare it with 0. (Oh, I just discovered that I can just use the first component and compare it with 1/2, which will work if my outputs are probabilites…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using NumPy, you should [deal with grids the NumPy way](//stackoverflow.com/a/32742943/1157100) instead of performing list comprehensions.

```
def probability_diff(x0, x1):
    probs = library_function(x0, x1)
    return probs[0] - probs[1]

results = np.vectorize(probability_diff)(X0[:, np.newaxis], X1)
```

I wouldn't try to get too clever with the lambdas.

Also, since the grid happens to be a square, you could use `X0` again instead of defining `X1`.

Comment: Good point about `np.vectorize`, didn't know about it, and a good reference to SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think using list comprehensions is generally considered Pythonic. As an improvement, you can opt to use generators for your `values` variable.

```
values = ((library_function(x0, x1) for x0 in X0) for x1 in X1)
results = [[a-b for a, b in row] for row in values]
```

By using a generator, you're using a constant amount of space for the `values` variable. I also think that using more descriptive variable names would be helpful.